# Como ubicar bien los texto en fotos de diferentes alturas y anchuras?

Tags: html, css

¿Cómo puedo poner el texto en la parte de abajo pero dejando unos 10 pixeles al final?

El texto deberia de verse de esta forma:

[image: Imagen]

[Aquí tengo mi código](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GEVX54Y36ZGN) donde el texto no esta bien ubicado en cada foto .

Comment: Ahi esta el link amigo :) en la parte de abajo.

Comment: Puedes utilizar un Botton: calc(100% - 10px); y ya no utilizar el transform

Comment: Muchas gracias A todos con el codigo de Levi Arista Funciona Perfecto :)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Envuelve a todos *contenedores* dentro de un `div` principal
- A ese `div` principal dale un distribución de tipo `flex`
- Para lograr que los elementos queden partiendo de *abajo hacía arriba* podemos aplicar el uso de `align-items` con un valor de `flex-end`
- Para lograr la separación podemos hacer uso de `space-around`
- A la clase que tienen en común todos los textos, le podemos dar un `margin` superior con un valor negativo para ubicarlo a los 10px de la base de cada imagen
- A la clase `contenedor` que identifica a donde están cada una de las imágenes y el texto le podemos dar un `margin` de 5px para lograr la separación

Código

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    
      * {
          box-sizing: border-box;
      }
    
      .contenedor-principal {
        align-items: flex-end;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
      }
      .contenedor {
        margin: 5px;
      }
      .texto {
        margin-top: -30px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #ffff;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="contenedor-principal">
       <div class="contenedor"  style="width:200px; height:250px;" alt="FLIPPPPP"/>
       <img src="https://img.poki.com/cdn-cgi/image/quality=78,width=314,height=314,fit=cover,g=0.5x0.5,f=auto/8cf9278eb561d8648e9f4ac49dd01638.jpg" width="200px" height="250px"/>
       <div class="texto">FLIPPPPP</div>
     </div>
       
     <div class="contenedor" style="width:200px; height:200px;" alt="MOUSEEEE"/>
       <img src="https://img.poki.com/cdn-cgi/image/quality=78,width=314,height=314,fit=cover,g=0.5x0.5,f=auto/8cf9278eb561d8648e9f4ac49dd01638.jpg" width="200px" height="200px"/>
       <div class="texto">MOUSEEEE</div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="contenedor" style="width:200px; height:150px;" alt="GRINGO22"/>
       <img src="https://img.poki.com/cdn-cgi/image/quality=78,width=314,height=314,fit=cover,g=0.5x0.5,f=auto/8cf9278eb561d8648e9f4ac49dd01638.jpg" width="200px" height="150px"/>
       <div class="texto">GRINGO22</div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="contenedor" style="width:100px; height:100px;" alt="RASTAAAA"/>
       <img src="https://img.poki.com/cdn-cgi/image/quality=78,width=314,height=314,fit=cover,g=0.5x0.5,f=auto/8cf9278eb561d8648e9f4ac49dd01638.jpg" width="100px" height="100px"/>
       <div class="texto">RASTAAAA</div>
     </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias ya esta SOLUCIONADO! :)

Answer (score 0):

Según veo estás haciendo un translate de 50% tanto en X y en Y.

Deberías cambiarlo a:

```
  transform: translate(-50%, -25px);
```

Para que se mueva 50% en el eje X y suba 25px (o la cantidad que desees) en Y.

De igual forma el posicionamiento realtivo al `top` lo cambiarías a 100% y quedaría tal como deseas.

Actualicé tu [snippet](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GEVXKBIUOMAK), además te dejo el ejemplo actualizado:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .contenedor {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid black;
      transition: transform .5s;
  }

  .texto {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -25px);
      border: 2px solid red;
      background-color:white;
     /* opacity:0;*/
      transition: transform .5s;
  }

  /*.texto:hover {
      -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
      opacity:1;
  }*/

  .contenedor:hover {
    -ms-transform: scale(1.04); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.04); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: scale(1.04); 
  }
  
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="contenedor"  style="width:200px; height:250px;" alt="FLIPPPPP"/>
   <img src="https://img.poki.com/cdn-cgi/image/quality=78,width=314,height=314,fit=cover,g=0.5x0.5,f=auto/8cf9278eb561d8648e9f4ac49dd01638.jpg" width="200px" height="250px"/>
   <div class="texto">FLIPPPPP</div>
 </div>
   
 <div class="contenedor" style="width:200px; height:200px;" alt="MOUSEEEE"/>
   <img src="https://img.poki.com/cdn-cgi/image/quality=78,width=314,height=314,fit=cover,g=0.5x0.5,f=auto/8cf9278eb561d8648e9f4ac49dd01638.jpg" width="200px" height="200px"/>
   <div class="texto">MOUSEEEE</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="contenedor" style="width:200px; height:150px;" alt="GRINGO22"/>
   <img src="https://img.poki.com/cdn-cgi/image/quality=78,width=314,height=314,fit=cover,g=0.5x0.5,f=auto/8cf9278eb561d8648e9f4ac49dd01638.jpg" width="200px" height="150px"/>
   <div class="texto">GRINGO22</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="contenedor" style="width:100px; height:100px;" alt="RASTAAAA"/>
   <img src="https://img.poki.com/cdn-cgi/image/quality=78,width=314,height=314,fit=cover,g=0.5x0.5,f=auto/8cf9278eb561d8648e9f4ac49dd01638.jpg" width="100px" height="100px"/>
   <div class="texto">RASTAAAA</div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

te dejo esta manera mas a mi parecer mas facil y apropiada.
**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="contenedor"  style="width:200px; height:250px;" alt="FLIPPPPP"/>
      <img src="" width="200px" height="250px"/>
      <div class="texto">FLIPPPPP</div>
    </div>
    <!-- todo tal cual lo pusiste -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.contenedor {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
    border: 1px solid black;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    & > img {
        position: absolute;
    }
    & > .texto {
        position: Relative;
        align-self: flex-end;
        border: 2px solid red;
        background-color: white;
        transition: transform 0.5s;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    &:hover {
        -ms-transform: scale(1.04); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.04); /* Safari 3-8 */
        transform: scale(1.04);
    }
}
```