# Que aparezca el TEXTO desde abajo al pasar el mouse sobre la imagen

Tags: html

lamento molestar de nuevo Pero como puedo hacer para que el texto salga desde la parte de abajo de las foto que estan en el ejemplo y el texto se quede en la posicion que esta actualmente?

[CODIGO DEL EJEMPLO](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GEVXKBIUOMAK)
Muchas gracias y espero no molestar :(

Saludos y bendiciones

Comment: ¿Tu objetivo es que el texto esté fuera de la imagen? Como en el ejemplo pero fuera?

Comment: ¿Tu pregunta no es la misma de aquí? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/356560/como-ubicar-bien-los-texto-en-fotos-de-diferentes-alturas-y-anchuras

Comment: Si no fuera la misma por favor marca la respuesta de la anterior como correcta para que pueda ayudar a alguien más que lo necesite ;)

Comment: Si es una nueva, ¿lo que necesitas es que tenga el efecto de una animación?

Comment: Son diferentes las dos preguntas!  Correcto Levi Arista que el texto no se vea abajo pero cuando pase el mouse que aparezca desde abajo.

Comment: Soy nuevo Levi y no se donde poner eso de Correcto :(